# Passing an object as an error message in validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

I want to know, is there a way that I can pass an object(let's say a Message instance) from the validation in the model's fields and retrieve them from the ModelState( or by using some other thing) instance. Why I'm asking this is, I want to differentiate between the validation error message types so I can display only the messages I want in the view at a time. (Ex : required messages shown before the unique validation messages.)

I was trying to use a custom created Message object which I can then distinguish using its messageType field. But as the validation only returns string messages, can't think of a way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you ok with reading the messages out of ModelState and determining type based on message content? That can be done if you set a custom message for all the validations.

Then you can evaluate each message looking for specific content and take action. Such as putting the word "Error" in the `Required` attribute and `Info` in the rest.

Here's a class you can use to test

**Model**

---

```
public class EmployeeViewModel {

    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Error")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Error")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Username")]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Email Address")]
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

---

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using TestApp.Models;

namespace TestApp.Controllers {

    public class HomeController : Controller {

        public ActionResult Index() {
            return RedirectToAction("Test");
        }

        public ActionResult Test() {
            var model = new EmployeeViewModel();
            return View(model);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Test(EmployeeViewModel model) {
            // Force an error on this property - THIS should be the only real error that gets returned back to the view
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Error on First Name");

            if(model.EmailAddress == null) // Add an INFO message
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Email Address Info");
            if (model.Username == null) // Add another INFO message
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Username Info");

            // Get the Real error off the ModelState
            var errors = GetRealErrors(ModelState);

            // clear out anything that the ModelState currently has in it's Errors collection
            foreach (var modelValue in ModelState.Values) {
                modelValue.Errors.Clear();
            }
            // Add the real errors back on to the ModelState
            foreach (var realError in errors) {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", realError.ErrorMessage);
            }
            return View(model);
        }

        private IEnumerable<ModelError> GetRealErrors(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, ModelState>> modelStateDictionary) {
            var errorMessages = new List<ModelError>() ;
            foreach (var keyValuePair in modelStateDictionary.Where(keyValuePair => keyValuePair.Value.Errors.Count > 0)) {
                errorMessages.AddRange(keyValuePair.Value.Errors.Where(error => !error.ErrorMessage.Contains("Info")));
            }
            return errorMessages;
        }
    }
}

private IEnumerable<ModelError> GetRealErrors(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, ModelState>> modelStateDictionary) {
    var errorMessages = new List<ModelError>() ;
    foreach (var keyValuePair in modelStateDictionary.Where(keyValuePair => keyValuePair.Value.Errors.Count > 0)) {
        errorMessages.AddRange(keyValuePair.Value.Errors.Where(error => !error.ErrorMessage.Contains("Info")));
    }
    return errorMessages;
}
```

**View**

---

```
@model TestApp.Models.EmployeeViewModel

<h2>Test</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>EmployeeViewModel</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Username)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Username)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Username)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmailAddress)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EmailAddress)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmailAddress)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Comment: I also thought of using strings. But is it a good practice to use strings for this?

Comment: I think you just need to look at what you are trying to achieve and ask yourself if you are working against the given framework or with it. Personally, I prefer to use the built in objects that are made for the specific purpose and modify them or to extend them to gain the missing functionality as opposed to reinventing the wheel. SO just ask yourself how your chosen method falls, into working with the system or against it.

Comment: What I want to do is differentiate between some error messages (Which I think pretty general scenario). I thought there would be a way to pass them as Message objects rather than Message strings so I don't wan't to operate on strings(which doesn't feel as the right thing to do). :)

Comment: Strings are ok here because that's what `ModelState` is using internally, nothing more than a `DictionaryList` of key-value pairs of strings.`ModelState` works the way it works because of the `DataAnnotations` that you place on your `ViewModel` properties. To achieve a different implementation you will need to write your own model binding system and extend `ModelState` to act as you want.